# xml parsing select

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

i start to learn C# and i need some help..
i try to connect an xml file from the internet and set all is data in an selectList

i try to run this code..

```
    XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("https://forex.boi.org.il/currency.xml");
    XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

    XPathExpression query = navigator.Compile("/CURRENCIES/CURRENCY");
    XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select(query);
    XPathNavigator nodesNavigator = nodes.Current;

    XPathNodeIterator nodesText = nodesNavigator.SelectDescendants(XPathNodeType.Text, false);

    while (nodesText.MoveNext())
    {
        selectList.Items.Add(nodesText.Current.Value);
    }
```

but when i run it it add all the data from the xml in the selectList i want to take only the CURRENCYCODE list.. USD..GBP..

how i can get the text of the CURRENCYCODE or other else(what it need..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more modern .NET XML API to make the task easier, using [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("https://forex.boi.org.il/currency.xml");
var currencies = doc.Root.Elements("CURRENCY").Elements("CURRENCYCODE");
//or if you prefer using XPath expression :
//var currencies = doc.XPathSelectElements("/CURRENCIES/CURRENCY/CURRENCYCODE");
foreach (var currency in currencies)
{
    selectList.Items.Add((string)currency);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to take only the CURRENCYCODE list

Simply use `//CURRENCYCODE` as the XPath expression to retrieve all currency codes.